# How can I set a public variable using getChildIndex in as3?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, var

I was coding a very simple program that lets you move around a circle, with also a rectangle in the stage. I wanted to make the circle get in front of the rectangle while you are dragging it, but when you released the mouse, the circle would be sent back.

I don't know how to set a public variable using the getChildIndex method. I don't really care about the rest of the code. I'm mainly interested in how can I make the getChildIndex method work with a public variable.

```
package code
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {           
        public var myCircleIndex:int = getChildIndex(myCircle);

        public function Main()
        {
            myCircle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClicking);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);
        }

        public function mouseClicking(e:MouseEvent): void
        {
            myCircle.startDrag();
            setChildIndex(myCircle, numChildren-1);
        }

        public function mouseReleased(e:MouseEvent): void
        {
            myCircle.stopDrag();
            setChildIndex(myCircle, myCircleIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using an instance ("myCircle") that I created directly in the stage as a movie clip.

The problem is in the public var I set at the beginning, it doesn't let me get the child index of myCircle, but if I put the same line inside a function, it works.
I know I could directly put the index number of myCircle in the last line (and erasing the public var myCircleIndex), but I figured out that there would be a way of using the getChildIndex for a public var in a class.

How do you use getChildIndex in a public variable inside a class?

Comment: All you need to do to put the circle behind the square is on release do addChild(square) or addChildAt(circle, 0);

Comment: You are overcomplicating things by trying to track a variable in my opinion. Let flash sort it out behind the scenes.

Comment: If you want a little more finesse and want to just put the circle directly behind the square (if there were 100 layers and the square is at level 12, but you aren't sure which level the square is at) you could do `addChildAt(circle, getChildIndex(square)-1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work, is because your timeline objects don't yet exist when the line `public var myCircleIndex:int` runs.

You shouldn't try and access non-primitive objects in your class level variable declarations for this very reason, as nothing else in the class is available yet when those vars are created.

Here is how you can refactor this (see the code comments):

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{           
    public var myCircleIndex:int;  //just create the reference here, don't assign it
    public var myCircle:flash.display.DisplayObject; //this line is just for better compile time checking and code completion, completely optional

    public function Main()
    {
        //wait for all the display stuff to be created before trying to access it.  The constructor function can run before timeline stuff is created, so it's not safe to reference stage or timeline objects here. 
        if(!stage){
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, timelineCreated);
        }else {
            timelineCreated(null);
        }
    }

    private function timelineCreated(e:Event):void {
        //now that we're certain the timeline stuff has been created, we can reference timeline objects and stage:

        //store the initial z-index of myCircle
        myCircleIndex = getChildIndex(myCircle);

        //the rest of your code that was in the construction -Main()- before
        myCircle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClicking);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);
    }

    //no change to any of the following stuff

    public function mouseClicking(e:MouseEvent): void
    {
        myCircle.startDrag();
        setChildIndex(myCircle, numChildren-1);
    }

    public function mouseReleased(e:MouseEvent): void
    {
        myCircle.stopDrag();
        setChildIndex(myCircle, myCircleIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do to put the circle behind the square is on release do `addChild(myRectangle)` or `addChildAt(myCircle, 0);`

You are overcomplicating things by trying to track a variable in my opinion. Let flash sort it out behind the scenes.

If you want a little more finesse and want to just put the circle directly behind the square (if there were 100 layers and the square is at level 12, but you aren't sure which level the square is at) you could do

```
addChildAt(myCircle, getChildIndex(myRectangle)-1);
```

**note**

> setChildIndex(myCircle, numChildren-1);

That's fine to do it that way. The more common way to do this is just

```
addChild(myCircle);
```

It does the exact same thing. Many people are confused by this thinking this would add a new `myCircle` but it just brings it to the front if it's already in the display list, and if it's not in the display list, it adds it to the display list at the top z-order (numChildren-1).

Comment: This is a good answer, but there could many reasons why tracking the z-index of circle is needed.  For instance, if the circle has other siblings (besides the rectangle) that it needs to be behind when not being dragged.  Not sure if you have enough information to conclude it's overcomplicated.